# Generating PDF RDLC report with Japaneses text

Tags: c#, pdf, rdlc

I have a report that correctly works in English but when it's translated to Japanese and exported to PDF it shows question marks instead of the text.

Comment: So only when converted to PDF does it screw up? When you run it, it works fine?  What if you try converting to Word or some other program?

Comment: It works ok when it exported to Excel

Comment: Are you using the ReportViewer? How did you specify the string resources? Are the resource strings (as unicode) been attached to the report? What is the Language for the Report. There is a Property Language on the Report. It might be set to "en-US". See if you can set this to the japan equivalent "??-??". If the report has to run for multiple cultures you have to set the language to '= User.Language;

Comment: @MichaelT: were you able to do this before on your machine?  Could it be that your PDF reader doesn't have access to the font; have you tried reading the file on another machine?

Comment: Which viewer do you use that "shows question marks instead of the text"? Or does it occur when printing?

Comment: @MichaelT: Can you provide a (link to a) sample of your `???` PDFs? I'd like to investigate if (a) the `???` represent glyphs of a genuined font used in the PDF but which isn't embedded (so the problem occurs while *viewing* the PDF), or (b) the `???` represent the real `?` glyphs (so the problem occurred when *generating* the PDF).

Comment: Kurt you can download pdf from this link https://docs.google.com/open?id=0ByeywhM8HLaPTkdpMWVhVFRHaHM

Comment: Sentient I change culture to ja-JP it did not helped. Limey I was unable to view it on any machine it reproducible on Japanese machines as well.

Comment: Here is an old link I found, this may help:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/2de5be42-d516-4d71-a8c2-ad2dea6d3504/

Comment: Can you please attach the original pdf.. so that we can test on that

Comment: You can download it from google doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to use font that actually has Japanese chars, apparently regular Ariel do not have them but Arial Unicode MS, MS Mincho, MS Gothic do.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the language packs for windows installed.  Could be generating the PDF's correctly but windows wouldn't know how to interpret them.

Comment: The solution to this problem is to use font that actually has Japanese chars, apparently regular Ariel do not have them but Arial Unicode MS, MS Mincho, MS Gothic do.

Comment: Even with Unicode fonts which are capable of foreign characters if the language packs aren't installed the characters would still get displayed incorrectly, or at least they have to be installed on the machine doing the translation to the new language.  This was a problem on a job I did when doing OCR of files to multiple language sets.  I did forget about the Unicode aspect of it though.